# Don't show socket message on APIs 26+ android devices

Tags: java, android, sockets, serversocket

I have tested my app on older devices APIs version and socket message is shown. But on 26+ version don't work. I don't understand why my function isn't working for newer version.

**SocketMessageReceiver.java**

```java
public class SocketMessageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    interface ISocketMessageReceiver {
        void sendSocketMessage(String socketMessage);
    }

    private static ISocketMessageReceiver iSocketMessageReceiver;
    private final String TAG = "DEBUG";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            iSocketMessageReceiver.sendSocketMessage(intent.getBundleExtra(SocketService.BUNDLE_DATA_KEY_VALUE).getString(SocketService.BUNDLE_DATA_KEY_VALUE));
    }

    public void registerCallback(ISocketMessageReceiver iSocketMessageReceiver) {
        this.iSocketMessageReceiver = iSocketMessageReceiver;
    }

}
```

**In my MainActivity.java**

```java
public void sendSocketMessage(String socketMessage) {
    lblMessage.setText(socketMessage);
    setNotificationMessage(socketMessage, "Порака") ;
}
```

**UPDATE:** I add BroadcasReceiver in onCreate, what other changes I need to make?

```java
private static SocketMessageReceiver.ISocketMessageReceiver iSocketMessageReceiver;

private ISocketInterface iSocketInterface;

private SocketMessageReceiver socketMessageReceiver;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

    BroadcastReceiver br = new SocketMessageReceiver();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
    this.registerReceiver(br, filter);

    iSocketMessageReceiver = this;

    socketMessageReceiver = new SocketMessageReceiver();
    socketMessageReceiver.registerCallback(iSocketMessageReceiver);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if that's the case, but it's possible that you are registering your receiver in the manifest.

Android O [introduced](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts#android_80) some limitations on registering broadcast receivers - generally, you can't register an implicit receiver in manifest apart from some [exceptions](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions.html).

So, you'll have to either register your receivers during [runtime](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts#context-registered-receivers) or stick to explicit broadcasts (this can be done by [setting intent's target component](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setComponent(android.content.ComponentName))).

**UPDATE**:

Here you are registering a receiver

```
this.registerReceiver(br, filter);
```

But after that you are creating a new instance of the `SocketMessageReceiver` and calling `registerCallback()` on it.

I think that what you want to do is to call `registerCallback()` on the same instance you are registering to receive broadcasts. Also, there's little need to have a variable for the `ISocketMessageReceiver` since your `Activity` implements it.

Related code in your activity could probable be like this

```java
class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
    implements SocketMessageReceiver.ISocketMessageReceiver {

    private SocketMessageReceiver mSocketReceiver = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        mSocketReceiver = new SocketMessageReceiver();
        mSocketReceiver.registerCallback(this);

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED);
        registerReceiver(mSocketReceiver, filter);
    }
}
```

Than, of course, you'll have to be careful and unregister  you activity as a `SocketMessageReceiver` callback according to activity's life cycle callbacks.

Anyway, this code is only to illustrate the idea, so I don't recommend using it in your app as it is.

Comment: OK, I update code in my question. I try using registering during runtime but stuck, I just start learning java :)